# Keep getting BLE UWP Unreachable error

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been trying to enumerate and connect to a BLE device using UWP.  My BLE server is a Raspberry Pi running windows IOT.
I am running the BLE Client on my laptop.  However, I usually get an Unreachable error when I try to enumerate the services on the Raspberry Pi.  In the below code the serviceResult.Status is usually Unreachable.  The Raspberry PI is placed right next to my laptop.

```
        device = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(bleDeviceAddress);
        GattDeviceServicesResult serviceResult = await device.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(guid);
        if (serviceResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
```

Comment: Have you tried `GetGattServicesAsync()` instead of `GetGattServicesForUuidAsync()`? What about the result?

Comment: Done that.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tested [this sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE)?

Comment: Yes, I have tested the very sample.  And still get Device Unreachable.

Comment: What's the os version of your desktop and raspberry pi?

Answer (score 0):

Try `Uncached` mode:

```
GattDeviceServicesResult serviceResult = await bleDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(guid, BluetoothCacheMode.Uncached);
```